# C++ , Switch case in a switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Is it possible to have a switch case in a switch case 3 times?  So if I have the main switch case and three in it, like:

```
switch(bla)
  case 1:
    switch(bla2)
       bla
       break;
 case 2:
    switch(bla2)
      bla
      break
 case 3:
   switch(bla2)
      bla
      break
```

So bla 2is the same string that I´m checking on.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: What do you expect that code to do?  Also note that in C++ you cannot `switch` over strings at all.

Comment: I have a code that I have a switch statement like that but i´m not getting the right outcome, so I was wondering if it isn´t maybe possible to use it like that.

Comment: I have a robot that is walking in a grid, so I have a switch statement to follow his walking.  If it makes any sense.

Comment: Looking at your pseudo-code, I have no idea what you expect it to do.  It is very difficult to help you if you don't tell us what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far and how it fails at doing what you want it to do.

Comment: One reason it may not work entirely as expected, is that you have some 'break' statements missing.

Comment: That you for your answer Ben, where is break missing?  I have it after each case statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may nest `switch` statements.

Unlike in your example, you would have to make proper use of braces (`{}`) so that it is clear to the computer what you want to do. I suppose you'd have to actually decide what you want to do, first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nested switches are possible. However you must use "{}".

> `switch(ch1) {
>
>      case 'A': 
>         cout << "This A is part of outer switch";
>         switch(ch2) {
>            case 'A':
>               cout << "This A is part of inner switch";
>               break;
>            case 'B': // ...
>         }
>         break;
>      case 'B': // ... }`

Check this out : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_nested_switch.htm